# Issue with Input statement

Tags: python, sorting, input

I am a newbie to Python and learning lists. Here is the program I have written for sorting numbers:

```
def sorting(final_input):
          final_output= []
          count = 0
          length = len(final_input)
          while count < length:
                    final_output.append(min(final_input))
                    final_input.remove(min(final_input))
                    count += 1
                    if count ==  (length): 
                              break
          return(final_output)
final_input = [5,6,57,531,9,1]
print(final_input)
print(sorting(final_input))
```

The above program works fine and gives the following output:

```
[5, 6, 57, 531, 9, 1]
[1, 5, 6, 9, 57, 531]
```

But when I give input with input command (as follows):

```
def sorting(final_input):
          final_output= []
          count = 0
          length = len(final_input)
          while count < length:
                    final_output.append(min(final_input))
                    final_input.remove(min(final_input))
                    count += 1
                    if count ==  (length): 
                              break
          return(final_output)

final_input = []
while True:
          user_input = input("Enter number or quit: ")
          if user_input == "quit":
                    break
          final_input.append(user_input)
print(final_input)
print(sorting(final_input))
```

The above program gives the following incorrect output. It is not clear to me what needs to be updated with ‘’input’’ statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Enter number or quit: 5
Enter number or quit: 6
Enter number or quit: 57
Enter number or quit: 531
Enter number or quit: 9
Enter number or quit: 1
Enter number or quit: quit
['5', '6', '57', '531', '9', '1']
['1', '5', '531', '57', '6', '9']
```

Comment: `user_input = int(input("Enter number or quit: "))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by kvmahesh, the return type of `input()` is always `str`. You need to convert it to `int` if you want numbers.

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter number or quit: ")
    if user_input == "quit":
        break

    try:
        final_input.append(int(user_input))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input!")
```

A `try...except` block is good to check if user gives some invalid input (e.g. `asdfg`).

Also, if you just want to sort the list, you can use `sorted()`:

```
final_input = sorted(final_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stdin` values are always of type `string`. so convert using `int` while appending at line `final_input.append(int(user_input))`:

```
def sorting(final_input):
      final_output= []
      count = 0
      length = len(final_input)
      while count < length:
                final_output.append(min(final_input))
                final_input.remove(min(final_input))
                count += 1
                if count ==  (length): 
                          break
      return(final_output)

final_input = []
while True:
         user_input = input("Enter number or quit: ")
         if user_input == "quit":
                   break
         final_input.append(int(user_input))
print(final_input)
print(sorting(final_input))
```

Output:

```
Enter number or quit: 3
Enter number or quit: 5
Enter number or quit: 1
Enter number or quit: 2
Enter number or quit: 100
Enter number or quit: quit
[3, 5, 1, 2, 100]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 100]
```

Comment: @Ahilan Anantha Krishnan: This worked. I tested in my local PC

Comment: @Ahilan Anantha Krishnan: Please accept the answer if you found this useful

Answer (score 0):

The input with this statement

> user_input = input("Enter number or quit: ")

Will be take data in form of string data type .so your input is taken a string . So sorting is NOT working

So make it int during appending

> final_input.append(int(user_input))

Comment: Think about what will happen if the user types `quit`.